# Html select tag is larger in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox

I use Asp.NET Mvc 3 for creating web page and so I detect that my comboboxes(html select-option tags) are different in Firefox and other browsers(Chrome and IE).

I try to manually add height to my dropdownlist, but it have same effect.

Here is some part of my code

```
<div id="filter-box" >
  <div id="car" >
    <p><label>@ViewResources.TuningStrings.GalleryFilterManufacturer</label></p>
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.CarName,new List<SelectListItem>(), new{id="carnames"})
    </p>
   </div>
   <div id="model">
    <p>
        <label>@ViewResources.TuningStrings.GalleryFilterModel</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ModelName, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "models"})
    </p>
    </div>
    <div id="year">
    <p>
        <label>@ViewResources.TuningStrings.GalleryFilterIssueYear</label>
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Year, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "years" })
    </p>
    </div>

    </div>
```

So, it's annoying that my filter-button has different position relative to my dropdownlists div.
Where is mistake?

Comment: I don't see you trying to add height anywhere. Also, where's your button?

Comment: Different browsers display UI elements differently. Quite often you also need to decrease the font-size to allow the dropdown to shrink to a given height.

Comment: Slandau, height is given in css file... It;s doesn't solve problem... And saying button, I have understood is my filter-button div))))

Comment: sqwk, changing font doesn't help too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Selects are very varried between browsers in terms of size. This is mainly due to the way they look being different between each other.  That is one tag that even with resets is hard to get exact cross browser.

Comment: Personally, I just live with it usually.  If you have specific CSS now with this code snippet, you can update your question with it and there may be some ideas that come from that.

Comment: There are random box-sizings across browsers. I suggest using some javascript plugin - for example [here](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/) or [here](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui)